# How to get MIGO data via FM or BAPI?

Tags: abap, bapi, function-module

Is there a BAPI or FM to get the data on the MIGO screen? I'm talking about the data it retrieves when pressing the execute button.

I tried debugging the code, but it doesn't seem to call a BAPI or FM.

[image: MIGO]

Regards

Comment: You mean, a BAPI to read goods receipt data? Did you search the web? (PS: screens developed a long time ago do updates without calling BAPIs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For retrieving data, You can use below BAPI.

```
BAPI_GOODSMVT_GETDETAIL
```

For Create / Goods Movement , You can use below BAPI.

```
BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE
```

regards,

Umar Abdullah